# Phaser P2 Physics : Line

Tags: javascript, game-physics, phaser-framework

I am facing a problem with my Phaser game. Here is a quick explanation.

I have a line drawn with this code:

```
var line = game.add.graphics(0,900);
line.lineStyle(18,0xffffff);
line.moveTo(0,0);
line.lineTo(lineWidth,0);
line.endFill();
```

The line is correctly displayed. Now I want this line to interact with other elements via P2 physics so I used this function

```
game.physics.p2.enable(line);
```

Here is the issue: only half of the line collides with other elements, the rest of it just goes through everything.

What am I missing here?

Comment: it should work, the `line.endFill()` is redundant there, cause it's just an line not a enclosed shape. Is it working with Arcade physics?

Comment: Just tested it and it doesn't seem to be working for me ether. ( https://jsfiddle.net/6hd20bp4/ )

Comment: also by setting `game.physics.p2.enable(line, true);` you can see whether the physics body is aligned to the right position or not. If ti does you may nbeed to play around with the body.offset values.

Comment: Updated my previous attempt (https://jsfiddle.net/6hd20bp4/1/), but still when the object bumps to another static object and starts rotating, the physics body somehow flies away from the object :] ..